# How to create fallback env variables with react-app-env

Tags: node.js, reactjs, url, create-react-app

I hava a scripts that define `env` variablies in my installer, after that I want to use this variable from `process.env` in my app.

**url.js**

```
const getLicenseFeatures = process.env.GET_LICENSE_FEATURES
const licenseManagement = process.env.LICENSE_MANAGEMENT

export default {
    getLicenseFeatures,
    licenseManagement
}
```

**package.json:**

```
    ...
      "scripts": {
            "start": "react-app-env start --env-file=.env",
      }
    ...
```

**.env**

```
GET_LICENSE = "http://localhost:2222/license"
MANAGEMENT = "http://localhost:2222"
```

But I want use `.env` variablaies as fallback, and set in my `.sh` something like this `cross-env GET_LICENSE='http://localhost:6006/license'`

So variable that were set in `.sh` should be main.

Comment: There's a config file in CRA that handles .env variables. You can take advantage of that and override those variables for the values you pass via cross-env.

Comment: @JulioBetta do you mean this?  `react-app-env start --env-file=.env cross-env &&  REACT_APP_LICENSE_MANAGEMENT=http://localhost:9999`

Comment: no, no... first off, you have to eject with `npm run eject`. then, inside the folder `configs` there's a file called `env.js` (there's a bunch of comments inside this file). I think that when you open it, you'll know what to do! ;)

Comment: I do not have config file, with latest CRA, i just need to create `.env` in root.
Create-react-app 1.0.0 added support for automatically reading configuration files for the three pre-defined environments: development, test, and production.